# SCardTransmit, how to read and write smartcard

Tags: c++, smartcard, rfid, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

I'm working on a printer, trying to read and write a contactless card.

This is the manual of the hardware and software I'm using:
[manual contactless](http://www.identive-infrastructure.com/support/download/SDI010.MANUAL.V1.13.pdf)

The process to ineract with the smart card (read and write in it), if I understood correctly, is:

1. Establish the Context using SCardEstablishContext()
2. Connect to the card through the selected reader using SCardConnect()
3. Talk to the card using SCardTransmit()

Is that correct?

Points 1 and 2 works ok and return 0 (SCARD_S_SUCCESS), but I have problems with SCardTransmit.

- If I want to read block 5 for example, this is the code I use:

  ```
   SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioRecvPci;

   DWORD dwActiveProtocol, dwSendLength, dwRecvLength;
   BYTE pbRecvBuffer[16];
   BYTE pbSendBuffer[] = {(BYTE)0xFC, (BYTE)0xB0,(BYTE)0x05, (BYTE)0x00, (BYTE)0x00};

   dwSendLength = sizeof(pbSendBuffer);
   dwRecvLength = sizeof(pbRecvBuffer);

    SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioSendPci;

       pioSendPci.dwProtocol=SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0;
       pioSendPci.cbPciLength= sizeof(pioSendPci);

   ret = SCardTransmit(cardHandle,                // SCard API
                          &pioSendPci, 
                          pbSendBuffer, dwSendLength,
            NULL, pbRecvBuffer, &dwRecvLength);
  ```

  It returns an error code 22.

  If I change SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 to SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1, it seems to work (I don't know if pbRecvBuffer values are correct): pbRecvBuffer has 2 bytes with values: 6e 00 and ret = 0.

  Have these values sense?

  I read SCardTransmit api ([SCardTransmit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and there I understand I have to use protocol T=0, does it mean I have to put SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 to work? In that case, why I receive an errror 22? What I'm doing wrong?
- If I want to write in block 5, I follow the same process: SCardEstablishContext, SCardConnect and SCardTransmit. I change pbSendBuffer to: {(BYTE)0xFC, (BYTE)0xD0,(BYTE)0x05, (BYTE)0x00, 0x10};, but I don't understand well where is the data, and what params I should put on SCardTransmit. Could you provide me an example  of this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What type of card do you use?

Answer (score -1):

```
`enter code here` we  must  check protocol using switch case and transmit like :


switch ( m_dwAP )
    {
    case SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0:
        dwErrorFlags = SCardTransmit(this->m_hCardHandle,
                        SCARD_PCI_T0,
                        rgbIN,
                        bIN,
                        NULL,
                        rgbOUTTra,
                        &uwBufferLen);
        break;
    case SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1:
        dwErrorFlags = SCardTransmit(this->m_hCardHandle,
                        SCARD_PCI_T1,
                        rgbIN,
                        bIN,
                        NULL,
                        rgbOUTTra,
                        &uwBufferLen);
        break;
}
here m_dwAP  is active protocol.
```